# how to call image from weather api using xmlPullParser?

Tags: java, android

```
 } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pressure")) {
      if (insideItem) {
           Pressure.add(xpp.nextText());
      }
 } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("weatherIconUrl")) {
      if (insideItem) {
           iconImg.add(xpp.nextText());
      }
```

I am trying to call weather items from weather api. All text items that I am trying to call are ok but `iconImg` is not. `iconImg.add(xpp.nextText())` gives an error. I probably shouldn't use imageview here, but I don't know what else to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the entire code:

```
 public class HavaDurumu2 extends FragmentActivity {

private String urll;
public TextView xmlShow;
private EditText lattitudeEditText;
private EditText longitudeEditText;
private Button devam;
public Intent dataShowIntent;
public TextView succcess;
public TextView appTitle;
public TextView lat;
public TextView lon;
GoogleMap googlelMap;
Marker mk;
Button fav;
TextView error;
Intent vj;
public static List<String> Time;
public static List<String> CTemperature;
public static List<String> Wind_Speed_Kmph;
public static List<String> Water_Temperature_C;
public static List<String> Humidity;
public static List<String> Significant_Wave_Height;
public static List<String> Swell_Height;
public static List<String> Swell_Direction;
public static List<String> Swell_Period;
public static List<String> Pressure;
public static List<String> Visibility;
public static List<String> Weather_Condition;
public static List<String> Warning_level;
public static List<Double> Wind_Speed_Kmph_Num;
public static List<Double> Wind_Speed_mps_Num;
public static List<String> Wind_Dir_Degree;
public static List<Double> Beaufort;
public static List<String> nearest_longitude;
public static List<String> nearest_latitude;
public static List<String> nearest_distance_mile;
public static List<String> date;
public static List<String> maxtempc;
public static List<String> mintempc;
public static List<String> nearest_location_name;
public static List<String> sunrise;
public static List<String> sunset;
public static List<ImageView> iconImg;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_havadurumu2);




    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        SupportMapFragment mapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googlelMap = mapfragment.getMap();
        lattitudeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enEditText);
        longitudeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.boyEditText);
        lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enlem);
        lon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boylam);
        devam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.devam);

        googlelMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(39, 30), 5.0f));


        lattitudeEditText.clearFocus();


        longitudeEditText.clearFocus();




        Time = new ArrayList<String>();
        CTemperature = new ArrayList<String>();
        Wind_Speed_Kmph = new ArrayList<String>();
        Water_Temperature_C = new ArrayList<String>();
        Humidity = new ArrayList<String>();

        Significant_Wave_Height = new ArrayList<String>();
        Swell_Height = new ArrayList<String>();
        Swell_Direction = new ArrayList<String>();
        Swell_Period = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pressure = new ArrayList<String>();
        Visibility = new ArrayList<String>();
        Warning_level = new ArrayList<String>();
        Wind_Dir_Degree = new ArrayList<String>();
        sunrise = new ArrayList<String>();
        sunset = new ArrayList<String>();
        Wind_Speed_Kmph_Num = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Wind_Speed_mps_Num = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Beaufort = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Weather_Condition = new ArrayList<String>();
        iconImg =new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        nearest_longitude = new ArrayList<String>();
        nearest_latitude = new ArrayList<String>();
        nearest_distance_mile = new ArrayList<String>();
        date = new ArrayList<String>();
        maxtempc = new ArrayList<String>();
        mintempc = new ArrayList<String>();
        nearest_location_name = new ArrayList<String>();




        String message = "Yer secmek için ekrana uzun basın";


        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
        googlelMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                if (mk == null) {


                    mk = googlelMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).snippet("Enlem : " + point.latitude + "Boylam : " + point.longitude).title("Kordinatlar"));
                    lattitudeEditText.setText(("" + point.latitude).substring(0, 9));
                    longitudeEditText.setText(("" + point.longitude).substring(0, 9));
                    //   fav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {


                    mk.remove();
                    mk = googlelMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).snippet("Enlem : " + point.latitude + "Boylam : " + point.longitude).title("Kordinatlar"));
                    lattitudeEditText.setText("" + point.latitude);
                    longitudeEditText.setText("" + point.longitude);


                }


            }
        });


    } else {
        String message = "Google Play servisi uygun değil";

        Toast.makeText(HavaDurumu2.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this),this,1001).show();
    }
}




public void clickHandler(View v) {




    if (lattitudeEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() && longitudeEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        String message = "Lütfen Bir Yer Seçin";
        Toast.makeText(HavaDurumu2.this, "Lütfen Bir Yer Seçin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (networkStatus(HavaDurumu2.this)) {
        urll = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/marine.ashx?q=" + lattitudeEditText.getText().toString() + "%2C" + longitudeEditText.getText().toString() + "&tp=3&lang=tr&format=xml&key=......";
        new LoadAssync().execute();


    } else {
        String message = "İnternet Bağlantısı Bulunamdı";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(0, 0, 300);
        toast.show();


    }


}


private class LoadAssync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HavaDurumu2.this);


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Bilgiler Alınıyor...");
        dialog.show();
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {


        try {
            getdata();


            updateDateandTemperature();
            updatedirection();
            updateAstronomy();
            updateweather();
            Log.i("", String.valueOf(date.size()) + "  " + String.valueOf(Wind_Dir_Degree.size()) + "  " + String.valueOf(sunrise.size()));




        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String message = "Hata oluştu";
            Toast.makeText(HavaDurumu2.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return null;


    }


    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {


        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();


            if (Time.size() == 0) {
                nearest_distance_mile.clear();
                nearest_latitude.clear();
                nearest_location_name.clear();
                nearest_longitude.clear();
                maxtempc.clear();
                mintempc.clear();
                date.clear();
                sunrise.clear();
                sunset.clear();




                String message = "Bu bölge için durum bilgisi yok";
                Toast.makeText(HavaDurumu2.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                    Intent m = new Intent(HavaDurumu2.this, ShowWeather.class);

                    startActivity(m);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    private void updatefeeds() {
        try {
            Time.clear();
            CTemperature.clear();
            Wind_Speed_Kmph.clear();
            Wind_Speed_Kmph_Num = new ArrayList<Double>();
            Water_Temperature_C.clear();
            Humidity.clear();
            ;
            Significant_Wave_Height.clear();
            Swell_Height.clear();
            Swell_Direction.clear();
            Swell_Period.clear();
            Pressure.clear();
            Visibility.clear();
            Warning_level.clear();
            Beaufort.clear();
            Wind_Dir_Degree.clear();
            Weather_Condition.clear();
            iconImg.clear();

            URL url = new URL(urll);


            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");


            boolean insideItem = false;


            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();


            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {


                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {


                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hourly")) {


                        insideItem = true;

                    }

                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("time")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Time.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tempc")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            CTemperature.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }

                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("windspeedKmph")) {


                        if (insideItem) {
                            Wind_Speed_Kmph.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("winddirdegree")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Wind_Dir_Degree.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("waterTemp_C")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Water_Temperature_C.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }

                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("humidity")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Humidity.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sigHeight_m")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Significant_Wave_Height.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("swellHeight_m")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Swell_Height.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("swellDir")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Swell_Direction.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("swellPeriod_secs")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Swell_Period.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("visibility")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Visibility.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pressure")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Pressure.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }

                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("weatherIconUrl")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            iconImg.add(xpp.nextText());

                        }

                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("lang_tr")) {

                        if (insideItem) {
                            Weather_Condition.add(xpp.nextText());
                            Log.i("", Weather_Condition.get(Weather_Condition.size() - 1));

                        }
                    }


                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hourly")) {


                    insideItem = false;
                }

                eventType = xpp.next();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {


            Log.i("", e.toString());
        }


    }


    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
        try {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public void updateDateandTemperature() {
        try {


            URL url = new URL(urll);


            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();


            date.clear();
            maxtempc.clear();
            mintempc.clear();


            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");


            boolean insideItem = false;

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();


            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {


                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {


                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("weather")) {


                        insideItem = true;


                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("date")) {


                        if (insideItem) {
                            date.add(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("maxtempc")) {


                        if (insideItem) {
                            maxtempc.add(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mintempc")) {


                        if (insideItem) {
                            mintempc.add(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    }


                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("weather")) {


                    insideItem = false;
                }


                eventType = xpp.next();

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }


    public void updateAstronomy() {
        try {


            URL url = new URL(urll);


            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();


            sunrise.clear();
            sunset.clear();


            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");


            boolean insideItem = false;


            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();


            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {


                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {


                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("astronomy")) {


                        insideItem = true;


                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sunrise")) {


                        if (insideItem) {
                            sunrise.add(xpp.nextText());


                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sunset")) {


                        if (insideItem) {
                            sunset.add(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    }


                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("weather")) {


                    insideItem = false;
                }

                eventType = xpp.next();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }


    public void getdata() {
        updatefeeds();


        for (int i = 0; i <= Wind_Speed_Kmph.size() - 1; i++)
            Wind_Speed_Kmph_Num.add(Double.parseDouble(Wind_Speed_Kmph.get(i)));


        for (int i = 0; i <= Wind_Speed_Kmph.size() - 1; i++)
            Wind_Speed_mps_Num.add(Wind_Speed_Kmph_Num.get(i) * 1000.0 / 3600.0);


        for (int i = 0; i <= Wind_Speed_mps_Num.size() - 1; i++)
            Beaufort.add(Math.cbrt((Wind_Speed_mps_Num.get(i) / 0.837) * (Wind_Speed_mps_Num.get(i) / 0.837)));


        updatewarninglevels();
    }

    public void updatedirection() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Swell_Direction.size(); i++) {
            if (Double.parseDouble(Swell_Direction.get(i)) >= 337.5 || Double.parseDouble(Swell_Direction.get(i)) <= 22.5)
                Swell_Direction.set(i, Swell_Direction.get(i) + "°K");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Swell_Direction.get(i)) <= 67.5)
                Swell_Direction.set(i, Swell_Direction.get(i) + "°KD");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Swell_Direction.get(i)) <= 112.5)
                Swell_Direction.set(i, Swell_Direction.get(i) + "°D");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Swell_Direction.get(i)) <= 157.5)
                Swell_Direction.set(i, Swell_Direction.get(i) + "°GD");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Swell_Direction.get(i)) <= 202.5)
                Swell_Direction.set(i, Swell_Direction.get(i) + "°G");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Swell_Direction.get(i)) <= 247.5)
                Swell_Direction.set(i, Swell_Direction.get(i) + "°GB");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Swell_Direction.get(i)) <= 292.5)
                Swell_Direction.set(i, Swell_Direction.get(i) + "°B");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Swell_Direction.get(i)) <= 337.5)
                Swell_Direction.set(i, Swell_Direction.get(i) + "°KB");
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < Wind_Dir_Degree.size(); i++) {
            if (Double.parseDouble(Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i)) >= 337.5 || Double.parseDouble(Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i)) <= 22.5)
                Wind_Dir_Degree.set(i, Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i) + "°K");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i)) <= 67.5)
                Wind_Dir_Degree.set(i, Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i) + "°KD");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i)) <= 112.5)
                Wind_Dir_Degree.set(i, Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i) + "°D");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i)) <= 157.5)
                Wind_Dir_Degree.set(i, Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i) + "°GD");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i)) <= 202.5)
                Wind_Dir_Degree.set(i, Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i) + "°G");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i)) <= 247.5)
                Wind_Dir_Degree.set(i, Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i) + "°GB");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i)) <= 292.5)
                Wind_Dir_Degree.set(i, Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i) + "°B");
            else if (Double.parseDouble(Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i)) <= 337.5)
                Wind_Dir_Degree.set(i, Wind_Dir_Degree.get(i) + "°KB");
        }

    }


    public void updatewarninglevels() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= Beaufort.size() - 1; i++) {

                if (Beaufort.get(i) > 0 && Beaufort.get(i) <= 3.5)
                    Warning_level.add("Sakin 0 - 3.5 Bofor Skalası");
                else if (Beaufort.get(i) <= 5.6)
                    Warning_level.add("Rüzgarlı 3.5- 5.5 Bofor Skalası");
                else if (Beaufort.get(i) <= 9.5)
                    Warning_level.add("Fırtına 5.6- 9.5 Bofor Skalası");
                else
                    Warning_level.add("Kasırga 9.5 - üstü Bofor Skalası");
        }
    }


    public void updateweather() {


        for (int i = 0; i <= Weather_Condition.size() - 1; i++) {


        }
    }
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use **String** instead.

String artistPic = null; instead of imageview

get the value like

artistPic = readArtistPic(parser);

Comment: thanks @Kumar . i am new to android. can you please clear it. i am calling the image from another activity.